# Teamspeak 3 Server Segfaults on Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, segmentation-fault

I've been running a bunch of software on my Ubuntu server, was running 10.04 for a few years and never bothered to update, it hit EOL this year and I finally got around to moving to 14.04 and my TS3 server started crashing randomly.

I figured it was just because I simply copied it over from the last install, fair enough, so I reformatted again just to be safe and did nothing but install a fresh copy of the latest 64-bit build of the TS3 server. Still crashing randomly anywhere between 10 hours and 24 hours after running.

I figured maybe I was doing something wrong, so I followed a tutorial for setting up the server rather than just winging it. I reformatted and reinstalled 14.04, followed the instructions in this tutorial: https://www.vultr.com/docs/creating-a-teamspeak-3-server-on-ubuntu-14

Still crashing.

Some further investigation revealed the cause is a segfault. /var/log/syslog contains the following at the time it crashed:

```
Nov 24 02:17:01 nimphio CRON[14516]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov 24 02:20:01 nimphio CRON[14553]: (nobody) CMD (/usr/local/bin/mpanel-memory-graph)
Nov 24 02:25:01 nimphio CRON[14638]: (nobody) CMD (/usr/local/bin/mpanel-memory-graph)
Nov 24 02:30:01 nimphio CRON[14707]: (nobody) CMD (/usr/local/bin/mpanel-memory-graph)
Nov 24 02:32:20 nimphio kernel: [71282.848718] ts3server_linux[1156]: segfault at 7f90f2781fe0 ip 00007f90f4bbd50c sp 00007f90f2781fe0 error 6 in libc-2.19.so[7f90f4aa4000+1bc000]
Nov 24 02:35:01 nimphio CRON[14778]: (nobody) CMD (/usr/local/bin/mpanel-memory-graph)
```

I have no idea what to try next short of rolling back to a previous version of Ubuntu. Is there anything I can do to fix this or is it purely going to be something that TS3 is doing that's suddenly a no-go on Ubuntu 14.04?